# MYSQL insert statement wont work. Error 1064 Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

This is my code:

```
INSERT INTO aggregate_summary (sampler_label,aggregate_report_count,average,aggr
egate_report_median,aggregate_report_90%_line,aggregate_report_min,aggregate_rep
ort_max,aggregate_report_error%,aggregate_report_rate,aggregate_report_bandwidth
,aggregate_report_stddev) VALUES ("2010 sf1","238","276","16","224","2","3121","
0.0","55.04162812210916","249.6223837881591","766.5325177049589"), ("TOTAL","238
","276","16","224","2","3121","0.0","55.04162812210916","249.6223837881591","766
.5325177049589")
```

I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'egate
>   _report_median,"aggregate_report_90%_line",aggregate_report_min,aggregate_r'
>   at line 1

Can someone help identify my problem thanks!

Comment: Invalid identifers, use back-ticks around aggregate_report_90%_line etc.

Comment: Judging for your question, your code has been justified to 80 columns with hard line breaks...

Comment: `%` is the mathematical modulo operator, so your field names are totally illegal.

Comment: You can't put whitespace (such as carriage returns) in the middle of an identifier.  That makes it *two* identifiers, neither of which exist.  Format your code to be human-readable and, as a bonus, the query parser would have an easier time understanding it.

Answer (score 3):

You must put any column names with spaces or punctuation (like percent signs) in backticks.

```
INSERT INTO foo ( `some column`, `other column %`, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define columns by putting them between ` character, because some of them are using [reserved words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html) for mysql like your column named average

```
INSERT INTO aggregate_summary (sampler_label,aggregate_report_count,`average`,`aggr
egate_report_median`,`aggregate_report_90%_line`,aggregate_report_min,aggregate_rep
ort_max,aggregate_report_error%,aggregate_report_rate,aggregate_report_bandwidth
,aggregate_report_stddev) VALUES ("2010 sf1","238","276","16","224","2","3121","
0.0","55.04162812210916","249.6223837881591","766.5325177049589"), ("TOTAL","238
","276","16","224","2","3121","0.0","55.04162812210916","249.6223837881591","766
.5325177049589")
```